# Authorize.net ARBUpdateSubscriptionRequest returning successful but not updating ARB record

Tags: xml, coldfusion, authorize.net

I'm using the ARBUpdateSubscriptionRequest method via XML and Coldfusion. When I update an existing ARB record with a new credit card number and expiration date, the response I get back is successful and without error. When I look at the ARB record after the update via the Authorize.net interface the card number has not been updated. I can only see the masked number but have tested with different numbers to verify that the last four digits do not update.

I'm able to create ARB records and cancel ARB records successfully. If I pass an invalid SubscriptionID I get an error in the response and also if I try to update a canceled record I also get an error in the response. Why on a update do I get a success response, but the ARB record is not updated? It is possible to update credit card and expiration date on an existing ARB record, correct?

I'm passing the following values:
amount,
subscriptionID,
totalOccurrences,
cardNumber,
expirationDate,
customerID

My response messagecode is I00001. My response messagetext is "successful" and the response result code is "OK". It does not appear that any ARB record info is actually updated when viewing the record through the Authorize.net ARB interface on their website.

Comment: If you check the merchant interface, do your changes appear correct?

Comment: No, that is the issue, when I check the merchant interface no changes have taken place when I use the ARBUpdateSubscriptionRequest method.   If I use the ARBCreateSubscriptionRequest or ARBCancelSubscriptionRequest method I do see the results immediately in the merchant interface.

Comment: If you wait a few minutes, does the corrected information appear in the merchant interface?

Comment: @rhldr - unfortunately, not. Even a day or later the record is not updated. If I use the create or cancel methods the results update right away.

Comment: I've tested this further in the sandbox and I'm able to update the subscription amount, but not the card number, expiration date or customer name. The api documentation lists that those values may be updated.

Comment: @rhldr The ARBUpdateSubscriptionRequest method does allow the updating of card numbers, correct? If I only pass a subscriptionID and an amount the amount is updated and I get a successful response. If I only pass subscriptionID and a new card number I also get a successful response, but the card number is not updated in the merchant interface. Without an error, how do I determine what the issue is?

Comment: I'm also able to replicate this behavior directly on the API reference page using my sandbox credentials. If you provide a valid subscriptionID and a new cardnumber, the response will be successful but card number does not change in associated record.

Comment: I would recommend reporting this using the contact us form at http://developer.authorize.net/support/contact_us/

Comment: @rhldr I've found the issue within the cfc I'm using to access the Authroize.net api.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in the Authorize.net Recurring Billing API CFC that I was using. It is not adding the card number and expiration date when creating the XML to send during update calls.